# In Charles Bukowski's "Some people" what is the meaning of phrase "It's Cherub, they say"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, poetry

I'm puzzled at a phrase in Charles Bukowski's poem "Some people".

The second paragraph reads:

> it’s Cherub, they’ll say,
>   and they pour wine down my throat
>   rub my chest
>   sprinkle me with oils.

Though I'm aware what Cherub is, I find it hard to understand what's that suppose to do with the story. Does that mean that 'they' are looking at the protagonist and proclaim that he's an angel and a nice person? Is there a different meaning I'm missing out here?

The poem itself can be found online, for example, here: https://www.artvilla.com/some-people-poem-by-charles-bukowski/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Charles Bukowski is saying that the people pouring wine down his throat, rubbing his chest, and sprinkling him with oils are calling **him** "Cherub"—presumably because he has the aspect of a cute little junior angel in the heavenly host.

Comment: Don't read him, he will ruin your mind :)

Comment: I wouldn't normally read Bukowski if you paid me but that's not the point. Please recognise, "I'm aware what Cherub is…" and "I find it hard to understand what's that suppose to do with the story" is the main point.

Can you explain either what Cherub is to you, or what that leaves to ask about the passage?

You might and in 60 years of listening I've never before heard that poems had paragraphs. 

If poems do have paragraphs, how would this passage qualify?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin apologies for being unclear. In this context by paragraph I meant the grouping of four lines. I do think it's a bit stupid to assume this is the general rule for sectioning a poem, but I think I've seen this particular piece somewhere else grouped that way.

Anyhow, what I understand Cherub is is a particular species of angels who are believed to be nice and charming and with no bad intentions. Why "they" proclaim it about the author is beyond my understanding as I can't get that information from the lines right before that statement.

Comment: If you consider more of the passage, doesn’t it become more obvious that Bukowski is less clear than you first thought?

Crazy or not, anyone who really lay down behind a couch for 3 or 4 days would be at serious risk or death from thirst… Does that matter, or not?

What Bukowski meant by “Cherub” rather than “a cherub” is anyone’s guess, unless you take it to a poetic criticism site.

Doesn’t “they'll find me… they'll say…” then “they (anything)” indicate a disregard for - I don’t suggest an ignorance of - convention and doesn’t that make most comment purely moot?